# In D, how can I aggregate results in a parallel foreach efficiently without using TaskPool.reduce?

Tags: d

Often in D, I want to write something akin to:

```
int result = 0;
foreach(someclass c; parallel(someclass_array)){
    result += somefunction(c);
}
```

In some cases, I can rewrite this as something like:

```
TaskPool.reduce!("a+b")(TaskPool.map!(somefunction)(c);
```

but in other cases this is not possible, for instance:

```
int result = 0;
someotherclass d;
int otherArg = 5;
foreach(someclass c; parallel(someclass_array)){
    result += d.somefunction(c, otherArg);
}
```

which won't work because somefunction would then be passed to map as a delegate (to support otherArg), but delegates don't currently mix with this pointers in D.

What I'd really like is some way to write:

```
int result = 0;
foreach(someclass c; parallel(someclass_array)){
    int tmp = somefunction(c);
    ... //something to indicate that this section is atomic
    result += tmp;
    ... //end of atomic section.
}
```

I see that D has semaphores, but using them seems overly clunky here. I've also tried atomicOp!("+="), but it appears to be undefined. Is there an idiomatic D way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [the `synchronized` block statement](http://dlang.org/statement.html#SynchronizedStatement).

```
int result = 0;
foreach(someclass c; parallel(someclass_array)){
    int tmp = somefunction(c);
    synchronized result += tmp;
}
```

Comment: Figured there had to be a nice way to do this. That's perfect, and I'll accept once the 10 minute window is up.

Answer (score 4):

For `atomicOp` `result` needs to be `shared`:

```
import core.atomic;
shared int result = 0;
foreach(someclass c; parallel(someclass_array)){
    int tmp = somefunction(c);
    result.atomicOp!"+="(tmp);
}
```

Comment: Another user suggested that synchronized has a speed disadvantage over atomic op, but then deleted that comment. If anyone has insights into the performance tradeoffs (won't they both use a semaphore under the hood?), that would make an interesting addition to the answer here.

Comment: No, atomic operations do not use a semaphore under the hood. To put it simply, they just instruct the CPU to make sure the value is not cached by any other CPUs/cores. Atomic operations are sufficient if you indeed just need to add an integer, but lock-free programming becomes much more complicated for cases more complex than that. For example, to append to an array, a `synchronized` block would be easiest, although replacing the array with a lock-free linked list would also be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use an concurrent receiver which collects all results. As example, consider this small program about calculating the factorial of a number in parallel: https://github.com/SommerEngineering/ParallelFactorial01

In line 81, the receiver gets defines by spawning a new thread. Line 90 shows, how this concurrent thread waits and reads a interim result from the parallel foreach threads. Line 124 shows the opposition, where the parallel foreach sends results to the receiver.

Finally, line 130 shows how the main thread i.e. main program waits until all threads are finished.